# Can i drop a column of a table in SQL server which is having a non clustered index defined on it

Tags: sql-server, alter, non-clustered-index

I have a table with huge record count . Some of the columns have a non clustered indexes defined on them .

we are required to alter/drop few columns which are having such indices defined.

I have directly alter/dropped the columns , but **did not get any error** like :

`Alter statement failed` .  It succeeded. So , here is my question is :

**Is it required to drop non clustered indexes on the columns which are going to be dropped/altered ?**

```
why it did give any errors similar to case of constraints/keys defined on them ?
```

**Updated :**

```
What incase of alteting a column for its size ? Is it supposed to throw any error ?
```

Comment: I'm confused... didn't you answer your question in your question?  "I have directly dropped the columns and did not get any error" - "Can I drop the columns?"

Comment: Does "I have directly dropped the columns and did not get any error" mean that you issued a SQL command (e.g., `ALTER TABLE yyy DROP xxx`), or that you used the graphical interface (right-click on the table and choose `Design`) to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is worded kind of strangely to me and I'm having trouble following *exactly* what you're asking... but this is easy enough to test yourself.

You cannot drop a column that has an index, see:

```
CREATE TABLE tempThing (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY key, someValue varchar(50))
GO
CREATE INDEX idxTemp ON dbo.tempThing (someValue)
GO
```

Then:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tempThing DROP COLUMN someValue
```

Gives error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The index 'idxTemp' is dependent on column 'someValue'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN someValue failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: May be silly question: What about a clustered index?

Comment: The same holds true for a clustered index.  Additionally, clustered indexes are often on your primary key column(s) so you would have that additional constraint to throw an error.

Comment: Yes , I agree with you . i have not dropped columns with indexes defined but only altered their size (increase). In this case , it did not throw any error . Is that correct ?

Comment: As long as you're only increasing the column size and not changing its type or decreasing the size then there will be no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this:

```
create table #t1(i1 int, i2 int)
create index a1 on #t1(i1)


alter table #t1 drop column i1
```

failed
with the message
`alter table drop column i1 failed because one or more objects access this`  `column.

Are you sure you had indexes that referred to those dropped column and they were dropped successfully?